# compare neighbourhood value with the mean value across all neighbourhoods in the city

Tags: descriptive-statistics, spatial

I have a dataset with all neighbourhoods in a city and their poverty rates. I would like to be able to create a vizualization that enables the user to select individual neighbourhoods and find out whether the poverty rate of that neighbourhood is significantly higher or lower than the city average across all neighbourhoods.

I am not sure what test to apply to achieve this.
Thank you very much!

Comment: Do you know how the poverty rate is defined in your specific data?  Also, do you have values of the denominators (total population in the neighborhood) for these rates?  And is the threshold for poverty rate the same across all neighborhoods, or does it differ by neighborhood (depending on what the median income in each neighborhood is, for example)?

Comment: Hi Alex, Thank you so much for your answer. The poverty rate is from census, it is just a percentage of people under an income threshold out of the total population in the neighbourhood. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to obtain the population counts in each neighborhood that were used as denominators in computing these poverty rates, for two reasons:

1. If population counts and poverty rates are very different across neighborhoods, then taking an average of rates can produce very different results than computing one rate for the entire city.  For example, if one neighborhood has 500 people with 10 living in poverty, while another has 100 people with 20 living in poverty, the average rate will be (2% + 20%)/2 = 11%, but a combined rate will be (10+20)/(500+100) = 5%.
2. Parametric statistical tests (t-tests, chi-square tests, etc.) require sample size for deriving a test statistic and computing a p-value. Or in the case of exact tests of goodness-of-fit, when there is no test statistic, counts are still needed for calculating the probability of obtaining the observed data under the null hypothesis.

If you are able to get those counts, you might possibly be able to use the [Binomial Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_test), which answers the question "if the true proportion is X%, what is the chance in Y number of trials that you'll observe a higher or lower number of events?"  I say "possibly" because this test is built on the assumption that observations are independent (in your case, that one person's outcome is independent of another person's outcome in the same neighborhood), which may or may not be valid with poverty (persons living in the same household would not be independent).

In your case, each person living in the neighborhood you are interested in would be considered one "trial", and each person living in poverty would be considered an "event".  The expected number of events would be the number of people living in poverty in this neighborhood if the rate matched the rest of the city, the "true" proportion ("X" above) would be the combined poverty rate for all other neighborhoods, and the observed number of events ("Y" above) would be the actual number of people living in poverty in your neighborhood of interest.

Binomial Test may not work in practice when there are large counts, because it requires calculating factorials of large values.  Instead, you can rely on the Likelihood Ratio test or Chi-Square Goodness-of-Fit test.  More info can be found here: http://www.biostathandbook.com/exactgof.html (on this page they use a different name for the Binomial Test: Exact test of goodness-of-fit).

Comment: Hi Alex, Thank you so much for your prompt and detailed message- that is very useful! I guess my main concern is regarding the spatial dependency of the neighbourhoods since they are contiguous polygons that compose the city, thus the observations (the neighbourhood values) are not independent, so I suspect I cannot apply classical statistics tests. I was thinking that I need to account for geography and for the potential spatial autocorrelation, so I am not sure what to do. Best regards!

Comment: I recommend that you modify the title or the wording of your question so it focuses specifically on the question of spatial correlation.  Based on a quick search, there is existing research on the goodness-of-fit tests in the realm of geospatial analysis.  See, e.g., https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1111/j.1538-4632.1999.tb00973.x

Comment: Hi Alex, Thank you so much. I will mark this question as answered and reword, reframe my question and repost it. Thank you!